# Ошибка в вычислении алгоритма Полига-Хеллмана

Tags: c++

При работе с маленькими числами, все прекрасно работает. Как перехожу на большие, вот тут появляются проблемы:
[Полиг-Хелман](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)
Таблицу значения я думаю правильно составил, думаю проблема в дальнейшей вычеслении. Может проблема с функцией pow из-за больших чисел?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

__int64 gcdex(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 &x, __int64 &y) {
    if (b == 0) {
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return a;
    }
    __int64 x1, y1;
    __int64 d1 = gcdex(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / b) * y1;
    return d1;
}

__int64 ReverseElement(__int64 a, __int64 N) {
    __int64 x, y, d;
    d = gcdex(a, N, x, y);
    if (d != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
        return x;
}

__int64 powmod(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 m) {
    unsigned __int64 res = 1;

    while (b > 0)
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % m;
            --b;
        }
        else {
            a = (a * a) % m;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        return res % m;
}

map<__int64, __int64> factorize(__int64 x) {
    map<__int64, __int64> factors;

    for (__int64 i = 2; i <= sqrt(x); i++) {
        while (x % i == 0) {
            factors[i]++;
            x /= i;
        }
    }

    if (x != 1) {
        factors[x]++;
    }

    return factors;
}

__int64 phi(__int64 n) {
    __int64 result = n;
    for (__int64 i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            while (n % i == 0)
                n /= i;
            result -= result / i;
        }
    if (n > 1)
        result -= result / n;
    return result;
}

__int64 china_alg(map<__int64, __int64> factor)
{
    __int64 k = 0;
    __int64 o = 1;
    auto it = factor.begin();
    __int64 u,e,h,x=0,w=0;

    while (w<factor.size())
    {
        o *= it->first;
        it++;
        w++;
    }
    it = factor.begin();
    for (__int64 i = 0; i < factor.size(); i++)
    {
        e = o / it->first;
        h=ReverseElement(e , it->first);
        if (h < 0)
            h = h+ it->first;
        x += it->second * e*h;
        x %= o;
        it++;
    }
    return x;
}

void algorithm(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 p)
{
    __int64 l = phi(p);
    cout << l << endl;
    auto ps=factorize(l);
    auto it = ps.begin();
    auto it2 = ps.begin();
    auto it3 = ps.begin();
    auto it4 = ps.end();
    //int r[10][10];
    __int64 **r;
    r = new __int64*[ps.size()];
    for (__int64 i = 0; i < ps.size(); i++)
    {
        r[i] = new __int64[it->first];
        it++;
    }
    __int64 t = 0;
    __int64 bk = 0;
    __int64 x0 = 0;
    __int64 ui = 0;
    __int64 step = 1;
    it = ps.begin();
    map<__int64, __int64> factorik;

    for (__int64 i = 0; i < ps.size(); i++)
    {
        for (__int64 j = 0; j < it->first; j++)
            r[i][j] = powmod(a, j*(p - 1) / it->first, p);
        it++;
    }
    it = ps.begin();
    //тут считает x
    do {
        for (__int64 h = 0; h < it->second; h++)
        {
            bk = powmod(b*pow(a,-x0), (p - 1) /(pow(it->first,(h+1))), p);
            for (__int64 i = 0; i < ps.size(); i++)
            {
                for (__int64 j = 0; j < it2->first; j++)
                {
                    if (r[i][j] == bk)
                    {
                        x0 = j;
                        ui += x0*pow(it->first,h);
                    }
                }
                it2++;
            }
            it2 = ps.begin();
        }

        x0 = 0;
        factorik[pow(it->first, it->second)] = ui;
        it++;
        ui = 0;
        it2 = ps.begin();
        t++;
    } while (t<ps.size());

    cout<<china_alg(factorik);
}


void main()
{
    algorithm(712312331,1323123132134231, 2305843009213693951);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй бинарное возведение в степень

```
long long binpow (long long a, long long n) {
    long long res = 1;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1)
            res *= a;
        a *= a;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```